# IntelliJ IDEA odd UI behavior in 12.10

Tags: gtk, gui, ide, intellij

Since I've updated to 12.10 I'm having a very bizarre behavior when running IntelliJ.

Notice how the "File" menu is 2/3 of the screen down instead of where it's supposed to be? This is the case when I activate it using the mouse or the Alt+F hot key.

I am using a dual screen setup.  IntelliJ is currently maximized on screen 2, and a console is maximized on screen 1.

The behavior isn't consistent, but if I use it long enough (a few hours) I usually observe it.

The only non-standard plugin I have is IdeaVM.  2 part question.  1. Has anyone else observed this behavior in IntelliJ or other apps?  2.  Any suggestions on how to fix it.

[image: Screenshot of behavior]

Comment: See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92800 for the details and possible workarounds (also check the linked issues).

Answer (score 2):

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11485#comment=27-393224  is the closest I found to a fix, which involves reverting to Oracle JDK's 1.6.

My problem also doesn't seem to be consistent.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  Sometimes a restart of intelliJ makes the issue go away for a period.

Either ways, it's a bug, and I hope IntelliJ fixes it at some point.  It doesn't seem to be Ubuntu specific.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of IntelliJ fixes this behavior.  At least it works for me on

Ubuntu 12.10 amd64, using oracle's java 7